# Show that $A$ is a flat $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, flatness

Let $R$ = $k[X]$, $A = R[Y,Z]/\langle YZ-X \rangle$. So I wanted to show that $A$ is a flat $R$-module; but I having a lot of trouble why tensoring with $A$ preserves injectivity between two $R$-module, say, $M, N$.

Any help or insights regarding this is appreciated, cheers

Comment: R is a PID, so flat = torsion-free.